# React, Redux: Loading data after navigate fails

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

right now I'm pretty new to react/redux and I'm trying to figure out, why I can't iterate through a bunch of data. The app is very simple:

I'm switching via Link to a page of table-entries -> the data get's loaded and displayed...everything is fine so far. But when creating a new entry and switching back to the previous page with *useNavigate*, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: books.books.map is not a function
```

**booksSlice.js:**

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book/';
const initialState = {
    books: [],
    status: 'idle', //'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed'
    error: null
};

export const getBooks = createAsyncThunk('api/book', async (id=null, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(BASE_URL);
        return response.data.results;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
});

export const postBook = createAsyncThunk('api/book', async(book, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(BASE_URL, book);
        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
});

const booksSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'books',
    initialState,
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder
            .addCase(getBooks.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'loading';
            })
            .addCase(getBooks.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.books = action.payload;
                state.status = 'succeeded';
            })
            .addCase(getBooks.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'failed';
                state.error = action.error.message;
            })
    }
});

export const selectAllBooks = (state) => state.books;
export default booksSlice.reducer;
```

**booksList.js:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getBooks, selectAllBooks } from './booksSlice';

const BooksList = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const books = useSelector(selectAllBooks);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getBooks());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return(
        <>
            <Stack sx={{ maxWidth: "80%", mx: "auto", mt: "2rem" }} spacing={2} direction="row">
                <Button variant="contained">
                    <Link className="link-create-book" to="create">Create Book</Link>
                </Button>
            </Stack>
            <TableContainer sx={{ maxWidth: "80%", mx: "auto", mt: "2rem" }} component={Paper}>
                <Table aria-label="simple table">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Description</TableCell>
                            <TableCell align="right">Author</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        { books.books && books.books.map(item => (
                            <TableRow
                                key={item.id}
                                sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
                            >
                                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{item.title}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{item.description.slice(0, 30)}...</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align="right">{item.full_author_name}</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        )) }
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
           </TableContainer>
        </>
    )
};
export default BooksList;
```

**booksCreate.js:**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { postBook } from './booksSlice';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const BooksCreate = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [content, setContent] = useState('')
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState('');

    const onTitleChanged = (e) => setTitle(e.target.value);
    const onContentChanged = (e) => setContent(e.target.value);
    const onAuthorChanged = (e) => setAuthor(e.target.value);

    const onSavePostClicked = () => {
        try {
            dispatch(postBook({                    
                title,
                description: content,
                author,
            })).unwrap();

            setTitle('');
            setContent('');
            setAuthor('');
            navigate('/book');
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Failed to post new book!', err);
        }
    };

    return(
        <section className="create-book-section">
            <h2>Add a new book</h2>
            <form>
                <label htmlFor="postTitle">Title:</label>
                <input type="text" id="postTitle" name="postTitle" value={title} onChange={onTitleChanged} />
                <label htmlFor="postDescription">Description:</label>
                <textarea id="postDescription" name="postDescription" value={content} onChange={onContentChanged} />
            <label htmlFor="postAuthor">Author:</label>
            <input type="text" id="postAuthor" name="postAuthor" value={author} onChange={onAuthorChanged} />
            <Stack sx={{ my: "1rem" }} spacing={2} direction="row">
                <Button variant="contained" onClick={onSavePostClicked} disabled={!canSave} >Create Book</Button>
                <Button variant="contained">
                    <Link className="link-create-book" to="/book">Back to books</Link>
                </Button>
            </Stack>
            </form>
        </section>
    )
};

export default BooksCreate;
```

In addition to that I've tried to console out the *response.data* and after displaying the error messages I can see the new data inside the console, although none of the data is displayed inside my window.
Please let me now if there is any more data you need to see.

Thanks for your help and have a great day!

Comment: can u provide a codepen version?

Comment: May be when navigating in between 'books.books' is undefined ? try '`books.books && books.books.map(...)' on you renderedBooks variable

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed You're right! This solves the problem with the error messages, but now the new data isn't loading and only the previos data is shown inside the table.

Comment: @finethen new data is not loading or  new data only loads after some time ? since you have not given any loaders previos data stays there while your api calls is running once done its gets updated, try setting empty state on page unmount or put a loader

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed No, it does not load at all! Only when switching between pages or hitting F5 the new data appears. Sorry to ask, but this is new to me: what do you mean with 'try setting empty state on page unmount or put a loader'? Could you explain a bit or send a link to doc? Anyway, thanks for your effort.

Comment: @finethen on component unmount reset the state back to empty array, or put a loader in your screen when api is fetching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...so looking back, the solution seams obvious: I made a mistake in one extraReducer - when the get-method fails - and forgot to include the reducer for the post-method!

```
.addCase(getBooks.rejected, (state, action) => {
    state.books = [];
    state.status = 'failed';
    state.error = action.error.message;
})
.addCase(postBook.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    state.books.unshift(action.payload);
    state.status = 'succeed';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `booksSlice.js` on createSlice, add this its an action to reset you state back to empty `[]`

```
reducers: {
    clearBooks(state){
      state.books= [];
    }
}

export const { 
  clearBooks
} = booksSlice.actions;
```

then on your `booksList.js` call this cation to clear the state when the component unmounts, you can either add an extra `useEffect` or edit the existing one

```
import { getBooks, selectAllBooks, clearBooks } from './booksSlice';
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getBooks());
   return () => {
       dispatch(clearBooks())
   }
}, [dispatch]);
```

Comment: Tried it out but there is no change in behaviour. But thanks again for your help and effort.